# AWS Lambda - If I Start a Thread, what Happens when the Lambda is Frozen/Thawed?

Tags: java, multithreading, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I've got a Java-based AWS Lambda function that starts a background thread. The thread runs a scheduled task that reports metrics to an external service.

According to [the Lambda docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-introduction-function.html), a Lambda function will be "frozen" for some period of time after it finishes executing, and can be "thawed" and re-used [if the function is triggered again](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/) in short order.

My question is about what happens to background threads when this happens. Say, for example, that I started my background thread in the constructor of the class that contains my handler function. According to the docs, all variables outside of the scope of the handler function will remain initialized, so my thread should still exist, but will it still be running? Will the fact that my thread is running in the background prevent the Lambda from finishing execution in the first place? Or will it just exceed the five minute limit because it hasn't entirely finished, even though the handler function has completed?

Comment: The background thread will stop executing when the Lambda function has reached its time limit. All the memory is essentially frozen in time, so when/if the contain is reused your background thread will just pick up where it left off.

Answer (score 4):

This is addressed in the official AWS blog [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/):

> But let’s say you have a background process running when the function
>   finishes – what happens to it if the container is reused? In this
>   case, Lambda will actually “freeze” the process and thaw it out the
>   next time you call the function (but *only* if the container is
>   reused, which isn’t a guarantee). So in the reuse case, your
>   background processes will still be there, but they won’t have been
>   executing while you were away.

Comment: Sure, but that excerpt is talking about background processes, not background threads. If my application starts a background thread, does it work the same way? Does the running thread count toward execution time (i.e. cause the Lambda to time out)?

Comment: I think the way I interpret it, as the process is frozen then *all* threads in the process are frozen. "Running" the "background" thread shouldn't be billed because Lambda knows when the function is finished (by returning value), at that time the process will be frozen anyway and nothing will be executed. It's similar to what happens when you press Ctrl+Z, the process is still there taking up RAM, but it's not executing anything.